# React Native 68.5: iOS archive upload - ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage: _SSL_CTX_set_options and _SSL_session_reused

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I would like to upload a React Native app to the app store. It works on simulator and real device, but when I create an archive and try to upload it, I got the following E-mail:

> Dear Developer, We identified one or more issues with a recent
> delivery for your app, "APP NAME" 3.2.6 (18). Please correct the
> following issues, then upload again.  ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage
>
> - The app references non-public symbols in APP NAME: _SSL_CTX_set_options, _SSL_session_reused. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your
>   method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future
>   submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may
>   be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so,
>   they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical
>   Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/
>   Best regards, The App Store Team

This is an old legacy project ported from React native 0.55 with the following dependencies:

> ```
> "@react-native-community/async-storage": "1.9.0",
> "@react-native-community/cli-debugger-ui": "3.0.0",
> "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
> "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "1.10.1",
> "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "5.4.2",
> "@react-navigation/native": "5.3.0",
> "@react-navigation/stack": "5.3.3",
> "@voximplant/react-native-foreground-service": "3.0.2",
> "create-react-class": "^15.7.0",
> "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
> "moment": "2.17.1",
> "patch-package": "6.2.2",
> "react": "17.0.2",
> "react-native": "0.68.5",
> "react-native-ble-manager": "8.4.3",
> "react-native-code-push": "6.2.0",
> "react-native-config": "^1.2.1",
> "react-native-device-info": "5.5.5",
> "react-native-exception-handler": "2.10.8",
> "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.10.3",
> "react-native-htmlview": "0.15.0",
> "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.5.6",
> "react-native-localize": "1.4.0",
> "react-native-push-notification": "8.1.1",
> "react-native-reanimated": "1.8.0",
> "react-native-restart": "0.0.15",
> "react-native-rss-parser": "1.4.0",
> "react-native-safe-area-context": "^1.0.0",
> "react-native-screens": "2.7.0",
> "react-native-splash-screen": "3.2.0",
> "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
> "react-native-swiper": "1.6.0",
> "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
> "realm": "10.24.0"
> ```

My Podfile is:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'targetname' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

I tried to clean the XCode and the Archive uses Release config.

How could I find the package causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. In short: My quickfix was to remove the use_flipper! from my podfile.

I describe the whole method, maybe I can help to somebody else with similar issues.

1. I searched every files for "SSL_CTX_set_options". It was defined in OpenSSL-Universal under ios/Pods. It means that my Podfile installed OpenSSL-Universal.
2. Checked my Podfile, it contains two require_relative statements, I checked their targets.ó for anything related to SSL.
3. node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods contains the definition of use_flipper! function (this was called from my podfile) and it installs OpenSSL-Universal. This is what caused this mess.

flipper is used for debugging, so it would be a better idea to call the use_flipper! function in debug mode.

After this, I still got a warning during uploading my archive:

> The app references non-public selectors in
> Payload/AppName.app/AppName: getAuthorizationStatus:, isPassthrough,
> onSuccess:, removeValuesForKeys:completion:

The uploaded archive can be tested with Testflight (I assume that it can be uploaded to AppStore, too). I didn't try to fix this issue, but you can find further information in this link: [The app references non-public selectors ins Payload/App.app/App...](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714996)